# Difference between the ways of applying .extend to a list in python

Tags: python, list, nltk, extend

I am not an expert in the python and I would like some experts to help me understand the difference in the output for the two ways I tried below

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words.extend(['from', 'subject'])
```

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english').extend(['from', 'subject'])
```

I thought the second approach was same as first one but I was wrong. I couldn't understand the reason behind this behavior change.

Comment: Because `list.extend` returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

**`list.extend()` extends the list but returns a None.**

This is the right way to use an `list.extend()`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
>>> stop_words.extend(['from', 'subject'])
```

---

Lets look at what `stop_words` type is:

```
>>> type(stop_words)
<class 'list'>
```

If we look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.**extend**(iterable)
>
> Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.

Here's the implementation of list extend function in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L872

We see that the function returns `Py_RETURN_NONE;`

To illustrate it in Python usage:

```
# We have a list `x`
>>> x = [1,2,3]
# We extend list `x` and assigns the output of `extend()` to `y`
>>> y = x.extend([4,5])
# We see that `x` is extended but `y` is assigned None.
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y
>>> type(y)
<class 'NoneType'>

# But if you extend `x` and then assigns output of `extend()` to `x`
# It assigns None to the `x`

>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x = x.extend([4,5])
>>> x
>>> type(x)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with examples. I could understand it out now. extend() function extends the list but returns none and not the extended list. Reference to the source code was helpful.

Comment: Glad it helps =)